# How to design and store history message in database in IM(instant message system)?

Tags: mysql, database-design

By storing historical messages in persist storage, we can achieve multi-device synchronization and message roaming.
But How to design the table schema and divide the table?
In my most immediate thoughts, maybe every chat group should have a table, and then the messages sent in the chat group or channel will be appended to the table.
In this way, we will have lots of tables, like `table group_123`,`table group_345`,`table group_${gid}`. The only question with this method is whether it will be bad to divide so many tables.
I have searched some answers before, and they are mostly stored in one big table, where `$gid` is just a field of the table.
Besides, the difference in this scene between mysql and mongodb also puzzles me. I can't figure out which one is better, like why use mysql or why not use mysql or why use mongodb or why not use mongodb.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I vote one table and recommending a database management system is Off Topic for SO I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

Be very wary of any design that starts, "I'll create a table per X," because whatever X is, it's likely to become too numerous, and soon you'll have thousands of tables, and discover that just managing the metadata becomes a burden.

In general, the way to approach relational table design is to follow rules of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Your table to store messages is a set of similar objects. Normalization does not make a distinction between sets that are modest in size versus large in size. If they are the same type of thing, they go in the same table. At least that's what normalization would guide us to do.

There are practical limits of any implementation, though, and you may find the need to bend the rules of normalization, by using partitioning or sharding of various forms. Even defining indexes is not called for by normalization, but it is a good idea to help optimize queries.

That's the key: any optimization strategy must be chosen in the context of *specific* queries that you need to run in your application. Optimization means to improve efficiency of *one* type of query, at the expense of other types of queries. You cannot choose which optimization strategy is best for your application without knowing the queries.

This is also the way to choose between relational and non-relational types of databases. Non-relational databases optimize for certain query types, so you need to know which queries are most important in your application before choosing any non-relational technology, or choosing which data model once you have chosen that technology.